# How to flash error if a macro not defined?

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc, winavr, avr-studio4

I want my program to flash compile time error like "LCD_PORT not defined" if it is not defined in program itself. For that I modified the header file like this

```
.
.
.
#if LCD_IO_MODE
#ifndef LCD_PORT
#error LCD_PORT not defined //(e.g. #define LCD_PORT PORTA/B/C/D)
#endif

#define LCD_DATA0_PORT   LCD_PORT     /**< port for 4bit data bit 0 */
#define LCD_DATA1_PORT   LCD_PORT     /**< port for 4bit data bit 1 */
.
.
.
...
```

But even after defining the LCD_PORT (like in the following program), it flashes the error.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <lcd.h>

#define LCD_PORT PORTA

int main(void)
{
    lcd_init(LCD_DISP_ON_CURSOR); 
    lcd_home();
    lcd_puts("Hello world!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you define the macro only **after** including the header file. What you need is this:

```
#define LCD_PORT PORTA

#include <lcd.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it before you include the header.